# How is Wild Companion worth it?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, druid, wild-shape

Tasha's Cauldron of Everything contains an optional class feature for druids, "Wild Companion":

> You gain the ability to summon a spirit that assumes an animal form: as an action, you can expend a use of your Wild Shape feature to cast the find familiar spell, without material components.
>
> When you cast the spell in this way, the familiar is a fey instead of a beast, and the familiar disappears after a number of hours equal to half your druid level.

It seems costly.  You get a fairly low-level benefit at the cost of a wild shape, which is a very valuable resource in short supply, especially at low levels.

I'm interested in how players have effectively used (or seen being used) the Wild Companion feature, such that it was worth the cost of the use.

In summary:

**How is Wild Companion worth it?**

Comment: Not sure why all the negative votes.  Search for questions with "worth it" in the title, there are plenty of them.  Seems entirely reasonable to ask how people have used the feature.

Comment: I would say the downvotes (and why I voted to close) is because of wording. You asked "how players have effectively used" the feature. Everyone can come with an answer; each one no more or less correct than the other. It's anecdotal, not absolute, so that cannot have ONE correct answer. You also directly ask, "Is it worth it?" What are you evaluating "worth" against? Some many find value, some will not. Does that make one side correct and the other incorrect? As stated, this is too open-ended for this venue.

Comment: @MivaScott Thanks for the feedback.  I'll re-evaluate the question compared to similar questions.  Although I thought asking for others' experience was good-subjective.

Answer (score 3):

#### It safer than scouting yourself.

I’ve played a Druid and a Wizard. In both cases, I was often called upon to do some scouting. As a Druid, it often involved using Wild Shape to inconspicuously scout as a small creature. This can be dangerous if you are found out - it can lead to capture or even death if you find yourself in a fight away from your companions. When I played a Wizard with *find familiar*, this wasn’t an issue. I could just snap my familiar out of existence if things got sticky, and I remained safely in the company of the party.

If you’re in a situation that would call for using Wild Shape to scout, it may be worthwhile to send the familiar instead.

Comment: So . . . maybe that's my issue . . . I am assuming it only lasts as long as wild shape.  If it lasts until dispelled, that's a a whole different cat.

Comment: @Jack Let me reread the features, brb.

Comment: @Jack I was misreading it, you’re right about the duration.

Comment: Duration notwithstanding, even Circle of the Moon druids don't get a wild shape with a fly speed until 8th level.  I haven't played with this Wild Companion option, but if it lets a druid of levels 2-7 summon a fey familiar with fly, or fly + invisibility (sprite), the utility for scouting is huge.

Comment: @kirt The comment about flying would make a good answer.  Regarding the sprite, that's not how I interpret find familiar.  I think the Wild Companion feature is just saying that your wild companion familiar can't be a celestial or fiend, and has to be a fey, but it still takes the usual find familiar animal forms.

Comment: @Jack I haven't used the feature, Thomas Markov has: I think it is more appropriate to offer my comment as a suggestion for him to expand his answer, since mine is more opinion and less experience based. Reading both the feature as written and the original spell, I agree that it is saying the spirit must be a fey but is limited to the forms available in the original spell. My point still stands, though - a hawk / owl / raven is often a better scout than anything you can do with Wild Shape before 8th level. I encourage you to think about the currency of worth, reword, and have this re-opened.

Comment: @Kirt That’s a good suggestion, I’ll work it in when I have time.

Comment: Regarding duration, it might be worth considering that wild shape recharges on a short rest... If you're at least 4th level and have a wild shape use left as you begin a short rest, you'll have an hour or more of companion time left after the rest ends, and all your wild shape uses. Might be useful, might not be, but you might as well use it.